# How to differentiate HTTP traffic by browser tab in Fiddler?

Tags: browser, fiddler

I've been having trouble for the last few weeks trying to figure out how to separate traffic by browser tabs. I am using Fiddler with chrome, and here is my problem: Lets say we have two tabs open, tab A, and tab B. I want method A to be run if there is HTTP traffic from tab A, and method B to run if there is HTTP traffic from tab B. Is there a way to distinguish between the traffic between tabs?

As a secondary question, is there a way to distinguish traffic between browsers as well? For example, separating Chrome traffic from Firefox traffic?

I have looked into other solutions, which propose to use the filter functionality, but this does not provide me with the functionality I need, as that only permits traffic from one tab and blocks any other traffic.